# Getting error on bundle install as (Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, ruby-2.0, gemfile

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 1.3.5) ruby

Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.2.3)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Above is the error that i am getting,already tried running 'gem install bundler'. It ran successfully,but bundle install is always throwing this error.Although its a dependancy gem,i have explicitly mentioned bundler gem in gemfile with the version 1.3.5,still getting the same error.Plz reply if anyone has come across such error or help me understand if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: gem update ; gem cleanup to get a new version of bundler

Comment: What is the output of `gem list bundler`? Are you using rbenv or rvm?

Comment: @Gjaldon The output is: bundler (1.3.5, 1.2.3)

Comment: @Gjaldon: and m using rvm....

Comment: This issue is fixed here https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2726, it will be merged soon with master.

Comment: What does `which bundle` output?

Answer (score 0):

you can force the bundler version in bundle install command like this:

bundle _1.2.3_ install.